# How can I make a Bézier curve have sharp and curved points?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

How can I make a [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) have sharp and curved points? Like a zig-zag. And also being able to make more 'circular' parts too.

(I want to make fig 2, but I can only get to 1 by creating curves added with the E button.)

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Being in *Edit Mode* you can select the desired curve point, press <kbd>V</kbd> and change the *Handle Type* to ***Vector***

[image]

[image]

To have even more control you can set the *Handle Type* to ***Free***

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by going into edit mode, selecting a vertex and pressing <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>. This will make the vertex scaled to one single point, and it will cease to have an effect on the curvature of those segments.

Like this:

**Before**:
[image]

**After**:
[image]

The vertices are still selectable, moveable, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the *Handle type* of the selected control vertices to *Vector* by pressing <kbd>V</kbd> *> Vector*:

[image]

This will make the segments between those vertices into straight lines.

Comment: You duplicated Gonzou . . . his isn't as fancy though XD

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Oops your right (though I started writing this when there were no answers :P).. Should I delete this? Or keep it for the answer ratio?

Comment: Keep it for sure!

Comment: This seems to have no effect in Blender 2.8 :-/

Comment: Is it possible to make the vertex with both handles zero length?
I scaled all to 0 and it seems to work but I'm wondering if it's possible to just remove the handles at all.